# WPF Label Justify & Distribute Text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a Label just displaying a title.

How can I justify the text? and how can I distribute the text? Can I use a label or do I have to use another control?

Answer (score 3):

`Label` doesn't have any text alignment property, however `TextBlock` does have text alignment properties so you can use justify if that's what you're looking for:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Justify" />
```

Comment: `Label`and `TextBlock` have different attributes and behave differently. Hence, this doesn't answer the question but rather avoids the problem. While the question is poorly set up, you also don't answer it.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt said you can only apply the `Justify` property on `TextBlock`, so the way to go is to put the `TextBlock` inside of the `Label` as below:

```
<Label
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="2"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    FontSize="26">
    <TextBlock 
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Text="Sample Text"
        TextAlignment="Justify"/>
</Label>
```